# Solve a matrix equation of the form $A=XB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

> Given matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$, is it possible to solve the matrix equation $A=XB$?

I don't know if this is feasible. It may even be quite easy in fact but I'm stuck with that equation in my work (I'm not a math specialist). I've tried to make the inverse of $B$, but as $B$ is not a square matrix in my data, I can't do that. In my data $A$ is $120 \times 170$ and $B$ is $10 \times 170$. I am expecting $X$ to be $120 \times10$. Any ideas?

EDIT:  matrix $B B^\top$ is invertible. Giving a $10 \times 10$ matrix.

Comment: Does $B$ have full row rank? If so, $B B^\top$ is invertible.

Comment: With R i was able to get the inverse of what you said yes. so i guess B is full row rank. It gave me a 10*10 Matrix

Comment: Then you can easily find $X$.

Comment: Ok... I guess it must seems pretty easy. I will edit to say that BBT is inversible. I am not really familiar with matrix manipulation, what should I calcul to get X.

Comment: Right-multiply both sides by $B^\top$ then right-multiply both sides by the inverse of $B B^\top$.

Comment: Thanks all for you help, you guys are quite reactive!

Comment: Note that what Rodrigo de Azevedo described gives necessary condition on $X$, namely $X = AB^\top(BB^\top)^{-1}$, but it's not sufficient in general, so you have to check if this $X$ is indeed a solution or not.

Comment: @Untitpoi  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can not be guaranteed solution. This is evident by the fact, that $A$ can has a rank up to $p$, while the rank of $XB$ is limited by $p$ (if we keep the order of your sizes). 
If you draw a picture of your matrices (just the boxes) you find, that you are searching for a low rank representation of $A$ with a specific set of right *singular* vectors. I italize because these are most likely not orthogonal.

You can approximate $A$ by your product. The best (I assume) way to do this, is by choosing the pseudo-inverse of $B$. (Matlab gives this by pinv).

Answer (score 1):

The system has solution $\iff Row(A)\subseteq Row(B)$ thus we can find a basis for $Row (B)$ and check that the condition is matched.

If $Row(A)\subseteq Row(B)$ we can obtain $X$ solving the system row by row

$$R_i(A)=R_i(X)B$$

Comment: I think it is possible to do my calcul line by line indeed as my data lines are individuals. But I don't understand what you mean by Row(A).

Comment: @Untitpoi it is the row space of A

Comment: @Untitpoi $A=XB$ has solution if and only if each row of A can obtained by a linear combination of B rows and the combination coefficients are the row entris for X

Answer (score 1):

The way to think of this is as a "multiple right-hand side problem"

$$A = X B $$
can be thought of as 
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c}
a_0^T \\
a_1^T \\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
x_0^T \\
x_1^T \\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right) B
=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
x_0^T B\\
x_1^T B\\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $ a_i^T $ and $ x_i^T $ are the rows of $ A $ and $ X $ indexed with $ i $, respectively.

What you recognize is that you are solving many $ a_i^T = x_i^T B $ problems.
Transpose both sides and you get $ B^T x_i = a_i $, which should look a lot more familiar, and then you can extend everything you know about solving such a system.